# Sync service stays awake even though the syncAdapter does nothing

Tags: android, android-service, battery, wakelock, android-syncadapter

### Background

We've added an account to the app so that it will be shown when the user clicks on a contact's image (as presented [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/20/getting-to-know-android-4-0-part-5-everything-changes-in-contacts-even-the-name/) on the "Contacts Cards" section).

For now, we don't need to have any functionality when syncing, so the code for "onPerformSync" is totally empty. Maybe later we will add code for it.

### The problem

For some reason, on some devices (like the Nexus 4 , with Android 4.3) , it seems that the Sync service stays awake for a very long time (at least 9 hours, could be more), even though it has nothing to do.

On such devices, the app drains the battery so it's crucial to fix this issue.

However, according to what I've read and heard, the functionality requires that we have a syncAdapter even if it doesn't need to do anything.

### The code

Actually there is nothing special with the code as it's almost identical with other samples. it even has a lot less code since we don't need syncing at the moment.

I will write it down nevertheless:

**SyncAdapter** :

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    public SyncAdapter (Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider,
            SyncResult syncResult) {
    }

}
```

**SyncService** :

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter (getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've decided to show more code in order to try to give more clues to this problem:

**manifest**:

```
<service
    android:name="...SyncService"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
        android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
        android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
</service>
```

**contacts.xml**

```
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ContactsDataKind
        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/....profile"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"/>

</ContactsSource>
```

**syncadapter.xml**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="....contacts"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="false" />
```

**AuthenticatorActivity**:

```
public class AuthenticatorActivity extends AccountAuthenticatorActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Intent res = new Intent();
        res.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, ...);
        res.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, ...);
        res.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, ...);
        final Account account = new Account(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_NAME, ...);
        final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, false);
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 0);
        setAccountAuthenticatorResult(res.getExtras());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, res);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### The question

Why does it occur?

We've followed all steps like on the samples yet the sync service keep staying alive, which (probably) holds the wake lock (as written [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/wakelocks-detect-no-sleep-issues-in-android-applications#_Toc358278564)) .

Perhaps I need to call "[setSyncAutomatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setSyncAutomatically%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)" or "[setIsSyncable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setIsSyncable%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)" ? If so, does it mean that syncAdapters are automatically set to sync by default? And where should I even call it ? In the "[confirmCredentials](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html#confirmCredentials%28android.accounts.AccountAuthenticatorResponse,%20android.accounts.Account,%20android.os.Bundle%29)" function?

Yet it still doesn't explain why the service keep running even though it has nothing to do, and when we will use the SyncAdapter for syncing we will have to deal with this problem again.

Comment: Can't help much with the main issue but in terms of where to call `setSyncAutomatically`. This probably should be done in `ActivityAccountAuthenticator` once the user has signed in. I believe `setIsSyncable` is by default on.

Comment: in which function exactly? in any case, all we did for now is to delay handling this problem, by disabling the syncAdapter.

Comment: From a method that handles the authentication response. When I get a response from the server the response (specifically an authtoken) is handed back to my `ActivityAccountAuthenticator` Activity, to a function called `onAuthenticationResult(String authToken)` for instance.

Comment: i see. thanks for the tip. still, it's not the main issue here ...

Comment: @Haraldo i can see that the problem still exists even when disabling the sincing. i've added setIsSyncable(...,0) and setSyncAutomatically(...,false) just a few lines before setAccountAuthenticatorResult() , setResult() and finish() . the problem is still there. the service still restarts itself, especially when i restart the device. i will now post some more code so that maybe it will give more clues to why it occurs.

Comment: i think i'm partially wrong on this. if the code wasn't called on the previous version , and now i update it with new one, since this code will run only once for adding the account, it won't be called and therefore won't disable the syncing.

Comment: So when you click the image of a contact you want what is happenning in that article section "Contacts Cards" to happen, right? If so I don't understand why you need a SyncAdaper at all. Like you said you are not even using it to sync. This I believe is an intent filter. Like the one used in a share button.

Comment: @Haraldo if i remove it, the account is removed too, so the card won't have the app stuff. the account is needed...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing it too with my own SyncAdapter (which *does* so stuff, but not several hours' worth!) and would love any pointers on addressing it

Comment: @andygeers I didn't, as I was told to do other stuff afterwards. Only thing I can see that has changed is this: ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(..., true); . I will now post the XML files. Not sure if they helped either.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this was caused by the same problem as [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673639/syncadapter-stays-awake-for-hours-on-end) - that there may have been code in your Application `onCreate` method that kicked in every time the SyncAdapter started up - even though `onPerformSync` itself did nothing, the Application code stopped it going back to sleep again.

Just a theory - and probably much too late to find out now!

Comment: Sorry, it is too late. Maybe in the future I will come back to this problem.